# How to apply mathematical operation on Character column in R

Tags: r

I have a column which have data as below:

```
"a"
"b"
"d"
"32.43"
"32.0000001"
```

Now i want to select only the value which are integers/whole numbers and which doesn't have `0.000001` in their decimal place (i.e value `32.43` here).
The issue here is that column is character so mathematical operation cant be applied.

Comment: Suppose if  `32.01` was also there in the vector, would you select that

Comment: 32.43 is not an integer.

Comment: yes i would also select 32.01 also in that case..i dont want to select a,b,d or values ending with 0.0000001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grep` to match one or more digits (`\\d+`) from the start of the string (`^`) followed by a `.` followed by 2 numbers (`\\d{2}`) before the end of the string (`$`).

```
as.numeric(grep('^\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?$', v1, value=TRUE))
#[1] 32.43
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, the OP doesn't want to select decimal numbers with >5 zeros after the `.` or any other non-numeric elements

```
grep('^\\d+(\\.[0-9]{1,4}[1-9]*)?$', v2, value=TRUE)
#[1] "32.43"    "41"       "41.5467"  "41.1"     "32.01"    "32.001"   "32.0001"  "32.00001"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("a", "b", "d", "32.43", "32.0000001" )
v2 <-  c("a", "b", "d", "32.43", "32.000001" , "41", 
  "41.5467", "41.1", "32.01", "32.001", "32.0001", "32.00001")
```

Comment: Thanks but say i have 41 or 41.5467 or 41.1.. Will this also select this.
Basically i am looking to select all integers/wholenumber of this coulmn which are not ending with 0.0000001

Comment: @Mayank Where exactly is the limit where you don't select a number?  You mentioned that `32.01` is selected by not `32.0000001`.  Do you select `32.001` or `32.00001`?

Comment: @Mayank For example `v1 <- c("a", "b", "d", "32.43", "32.0000001" , "41", "41.5467", "41.1", "32.01");grep('^\\d+(\\.[0-9][1-9]*)?$', v1, value=TRUE)
#[1] "32.43"   "41"      "41.5467" "41.1"    "32.01"`  It depends on your condition which is unclear.

Comment: i dont want only numbers  that have decimal places .000001 to be selected.

Comment: i dont want only numbers  that have decimal places .000001 to be selected.
32.01,32.001,32.0001,32.00001 can be selected but not 32.000001.
Thus apart from values ending with .000001 all values need to be selected...If you can tell me what this function of yours is doing may be i can rewrite myself since i am finding difficulty to interpret grep function here

Comment: Thanks Arun. This solves my problem..Also can you tell me if the output values from grep needs to be updated in same vector with "A", how can we do that?

Comment: In that case just do `i1 <- grep('^\\d+(\\.[0-9][1-9]*)?$', A); A <- A[i1]`